# PHP - Numbers, number digit

Tags: php, json, numbers

i have a question about numbers in php.

Example i have this numbers

> 1111122333344

I want to show that number one have five digits, number two have two digits and number three have four digits and for have two digits. I want to seperate it. But how can i do that? Thank you for help.
Here is example:

```html
Number that i have 1111122333344
number 1 have = 5 (digits)
number 2 have = 2 (digits)
number 3 have = 4 (digits)
number 4 have = 2 (digits)
```

I have tried this and its not working

```html
$numbers = '1111122333344';
if ($numbers > 3) {
echo '2';
}
```

(Sry for bad eng) Thank you!

Comment: I dont know much about php so i need really help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this

```
<?php
$n=1111122333344;
echo "
number 1 have = ".substr_count($n, '1')." (digits)<br>
number 2 have = ".substr_count($n, '2')." (digits)<br>
number 3 have = ".substr_count($n, '3')." (digits)<br>
number 4 have = ".substr_count($n, '4')." (digits)<br>
";
?>
```

Comment: What if someday `$n` is `111112233334455` or has 6 7 8 9

Comment: we have use in substr_count for all 0-9. If you want avoid 0 digit of any number you can use if condtion

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
<?php
$numbers = str_split('111132444423334545');

var_dump(array_count_values($numbers));
?>
```

The output will be:

```
array(5) {
  [1]=>
  int(4)
  [3]=>
  int(4)
  [2]=>
  int(2)
  [4]=>
  int(6)
  [5]=>
  int(2)
}
```

[str_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) converts a string to an array.
[array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) returns an array using the values of array as keys and their frequency in array as values.